# Gtk::Window icon set with set_icon_name doesn't work on wayland

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

I'm trying to solve [a synfig issue](https://github.com/synfig/synfig/issues/1063) by testing out this sample program:

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

class HelloWindow : public Gtk::Window {
        public:
                HelloWindow();
                ~HelloWindow();
};

HelloWindow::HelloWindow()
{
        set_icon_name("org.synfig.SynfigStudio"); // <- name copied from synfig build

        property_title() = "Hello Window";
        property_default_width() = 320;
        property_default_height() = 240;

        present();
}

HelloWindow::~HelloWindow()
{
}

int main()
{
        Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.Hello");

        HelloWindow hello;

        return app->run(hello);
}
```

I copied synfig hicolor icons to my ~/.icons/ directory.

On running the sample program, the icon is displayed on X11 GNOME session

- [top panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYjfa.png)
- [overview panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abUHe.png)

Whereas, on Wayland, I get executable icons as replacement

- [top panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZfwL.png)
- [overview panel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pa6Lu.png)

Also, tried with pre-installed system icons, like `"org.gnome.Calculator"`

The window icon works on X11 but not on Wayland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer is not mine. A user from GTK irc gave this and I'm only quoting the conversation*

Here is the chat history: [Riot | GTK](https://matrix.to/#/!aUhETchlgthwWVQzhi:matrix.org/$15894551949718SGglX:gnome.org?via=gnome.org&via=matrix.org&via=breadpirates.chat)

And the quoted answer

> normally you have a desktop file
>
> and the icon (and the name) are used from there
>
> so if synfig studio doens't have one, well, add one

Comment: That is indeed correct for Linux. But what about windows? I cross compiled my gtk app to Windows. But how to get an icon under Windows?

Comment: For Windows, I remember packaging *.ico files to my gtk app using a 3rd party tool. Works. Sadly I don't remember that tool's name :(

Comment: I found the tool's name: [rcedit](https://github.com/electron/rcedit). And just for quick review of how to export png icon file to *.ico files [Changing application icon for Windows](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/workflow/export/changing_application_icon_for_windows.html)

Comment: Well this is for Godot. Not when you are using c++ I think. Anyway, yes you need an ico file but you also need a windows resource file. I just found out what such file needs to be compiled with windres compiler (rc file compiler).